# Proof Laplace Transforms from Prudnikov Vol. 4

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I found the following integral in $\textit{Integrals and Series Volume 4: Direct Laplace Transform}$ (Prudnikov and Brychkov) p.312 (3.14.2.1)

$$F_1(p)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{H}_0^{(1)}\left(a \, \sqrt{x^2-b^2}\right)\, \mathrm{e}^{-p\,x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-b\,\sqrt{p^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{p^2+a^2}}\,\left(1-\frac{2\,\mathrm{i}}{\pi}\,\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{p+\sqrt{p^2+a^2}}{a}\right)\right)$$
with the given restrictions $b>0$ and Re$(p)>|$Im$(a)|$ and $\mathrm{H}_0^{(1)}()$ the Hankel function of the first kind.

Can anybody tell me how this result is derivated? And if the restrictions can be relaxed?

The integral on p.357 (3.16.5.4) would also be really interesting
$$F_2(p)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-b^2}}\mathrm{K}_\nu\left(a \, \sqrt{x^2-b^2}\right)\, \mathrm{e}^{-p\,x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \\\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{sec}\left(\frac{\nu\,\pi}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{K}_{\nu/2}\left(\frac{b\,(p-\sqrt{p^2-a^2})}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{K}_{\nu/2}\left(\frac{b\,(p+\sqrt{p^2-a^2})}{2}\right)$$
with the restrictions $|$Re$(\nu)<1|$, $b>0$ and Re$(p+a)>0$. I am wondering if this integral becomes divergent if $\nu \to 1$. Especially since I think that $F_2(p)$ can be computed with $\frac{\partial\,F_1(p)}{\partial\,b}$ and the relation between $\mathrm{H}_1^{(1)}()$ and $\mathrm{K}_1()$.

I am interested, because this could maybe solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906124/356786)

Thank you.

Comment: 1) It is not impossible that this result has been found using complex analysis. 2) A general remark: You should first simplify your problem by taking for example $a=b=1$ one spots $\ln{(p+\sqrt{1+p^2})}$ which is $argsinh(p)$ 3) by separating real and imaginary parts because $H_{0}^1(t)=J_0(t)+iY_0(t)$ and computing Laplace transforms of each one 4) Moreover the integration interval should be $[0,b]$...

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. What do you mean with 4)?

Comment: I mean that you must be aware of the meaning of what you integrate, knowing the bounds on the integral : in particular, what meaning do you attribute to $\sqrt{x^2-b^2}$ if $x>b$ ?

Comment: I am wondering if the used the Mehler-Sonine integral represenation to solve this problem. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9
Doesn't $sqrt{x^2-b^2}$ simple change from complex to real?

Comment: We can find these integral representations in Magnus and Oberhettinger book "Formulas and Theorems for the Special Functions of Mathematical Physics" on page 81 and 82. I am not sure what they mean with Re$(z\pm\zeta)>0$. Is this an "or" or an "and" for the $\pm$.