# Integral evaluation through series expansion

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the integral ([see also here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906124/356786))

$$I(\gamma,b,\beta)=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\beta^2+b^2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+\gamma^2\,\frac{\beta^2}{b^2+\beta^2}} \, e^{- \sqrt{\beta^2+b^2} \, \sqrt{x^2+\gamma^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I was wondering if it makes any sense to use the power series of

$$e^{- \sqrt{\beta^2+b^2} \, \sqrt{x^2+\gamma^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(- \sqrt{\beta^2+b^2} \, \sqrt{x^2+\gamma^2})^n}{n!}$$

and the indefinite integral (from Mathematica)

$$I_1(x,\gamma,b,\beta,n)=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\beta^2+b^2}}\int \frac{(- \sqrt{\beta^2+b^2} \, \sqrt{x^2+\gamma^2})^n}{\left(x^2+\gamma^2\,\frac{\beta^2}{b^2+\beta^2}\right)n!}\, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{(-1)^n}{\beta\,\gamma^2\,n!}\,x\,(\beta^2+b^2)^{\frac{1+n}{2}}\,\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\gamma^2}\right)^{-n/2}\,(x^2+\gamma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\mathrm{F}_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2};-\tfrac{n}{2},1,\tfrac{3}{2};-\tfrac{x^2}{\gamma^2},-\tfrac{x^2\,(b^2+\beta^2)}{\beta^2\,\gamma^2}\right)$$

with $\mathrm{F}_1$ the [Appell Hypergemetric Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html).

Since $$\lim_{x\to0} I_1(x,\gamma,b,\beta,n)=0$$
I would guess that
$$I(\gamma,b,\beta)= \lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\beta\,\gamma^2\,n!}\,x\,(\beta^2+b^2)^{\frac{1+n}{2}}\,\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\gamma^2}\right)^{-n/2}\,(x^2+\gamma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\mathrm{F}_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2};-\tfrac{n}{2},1,\tfrac{3}{2};-\tfrac{x^2}{\gamma^2},-\tfrac{x^2\,(b^2+\beta^2)}{\beta^2\,\gamma^2}\right)$$

If this is even correct, is there a way to get a closed form solution from this approach? I know there is a solution for $b=0$.
Thank you.

Edit: I think it can be simplified to
$$I(\gamma,b,\beta)= \lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\beta\,\gamma^{2-n}\,n!}\,x\,(\beta^2+b^2)^{\frac{1+n}{2}}\,\,\mathrm{F}_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2};-\tfrac{n}{2},1,\tfrac{3}{2};-\tfrac{x^2}{\gamma^2},-\tfrac{x^2\,(b^2+\beta^2)}{\beta^2\,\gamma^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get the parameters in a more convenient form:

$$I=\frac{\beta}{p} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-p \sqrt{t^2+1}}}{t^2+q^2}dt$$

Where:

$$p=\gamma \sqrt{\beta^2+b^2}, \qquad q^2=\frac{\beta^2}{b^2+\beta^2} \leq 1$$

Now consider the new integral, and let's make another substitution:

$$t=\sinh u$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-p \sqrt{t^2+1}}}{t^2+q^2}dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-p \cosh u}\cosh u}{\cosh^2 u-s^2}du=f(p,s)$$

Where:

$$s^2=1-q^2 \leq 1$$

We can expand the denominator as a geometric series for the full range of the variable, getting the Taylor series in $s$:

$$f(p,s)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty s^{2k} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-p \cosh u}}{\cosh^{2k+1} u}du$$

The integrals in general don't have a closed form (though they all converge, so can be computed numerically). However, we can obtain a differential equation in $p$.

Let's now denote $f(p,s)=g(p)$, leaving $s$ as a general parameter. Then:

$$g''(p)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty s^{2k} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-p \cosh u}}{\cosh^{2k-1} u}du= \\ =\int_0^\infty  e^{-p \cosh u} \cosh u~du+s^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty s^{2k} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-p \cosh u}}{\cosh^{2k+1} u}du$$

The first integral has a closed form in terms of a modified Bessel function. Finally we obtain a second order ODE:

> $$g''(p)-s^2 g(p)-K_1 (p)=0 \tag{1}$$

The initial conditions are a little more complicated. From the original integral we have:

$$g(0)=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{1-s^2}}$$

We can use $ g( \infty)=0$ as another condition, however it's not suitable for numerical solution of the ODE. In that case, we can just numerically compute some value, like $g(1)$ or $g'(1)$. The derivative at $0$ diverges.

The equation has an analytic solution, but not in closed form. The homogeneous part obviously gives an exponential solution, but the Bessel function makes the final solution much more complicated.

---

Here's a numerical solution of the ODE (blue) compared to numerical integration (orange). Both are done in Mathematica for $s=e^{-1}$:

[image]

---

For $s=1$, Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica give a closed form general solution to the ODE in herms of Meijer G-function:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%27%27%5Bx%5D-g%5Bx%5D-BesselK%5B1,x%5D%3D0

> $$g(p)=-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\pi }} \left( \pi  e^{p} G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(2 p\left|
> \begin{array}{c}
>  1,\frac{3}{2} \\
>  0,0,2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right.\right)+e^{-p}G_{2,3}^{3,1}\left(2 p\left|
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \frac{3}{2},1 \\
>  0,0,2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right.\right)\right)+c_1 e^p+c_2 e^{-p}$$
>
> $$s=1$$

Note that for $s=1$ the original integral diverges.

As such, I doubt there's anything more simple, especially for general $s$.